# DOM returns wrong text

Tags: php, html, dom

Im trying to make something which retrieves event data, but when it tries to echo some special tokens I get weird text back.

This is the code:

```html
foreach( $new_html->find( 'div#desc' ) as $desc ) {
  echo $desc;
  echo "</br>";
}
```

and this is what it returns:

> ClubCuccini Persian Valentines Party
>   â–€â–€â–€â–€ Friday 12th February 2016 â–€â–€â–€â–€
>   ClubCuccini would like to invite you all to one of the most romantic and exciting events of the year in L8 Club , one of the most exclusive place in London.

but it should be returning:

> ▀▀▀▀ Friday 12th February 2016 ▀▀▀▀
>   ClubCuccini would like to invite you all to one of the most romantic and exciting events of the year in L8 Club , one of the most exclusive place in London.

Any ideas how to get the good text form?

Comment: can you show the content of any node with id="`desc`" from html markup ?

Comment: yiu have some encoding issue. make sure everything is utf8, including your page's content-type: text/html; encoding:utf8

Comment: it seems that the page where i was testing on wasnt on utf8. but when implemented on the origenal page it works fine